# Make array, compare and get value from it

Tags: jquery, arrays

What I like to achieve is this:

```
    var price = $.cookie('cur_price'); //this is USD, EUR or GBP
    var price = 'USD'; //this could be an outcome

        var USD = 30; //to put this in a array
        var EUR = 24; //seems the right way
        var GBP = 30;

           var active = Get from array the value where price == array value

    $('#price').html(active);
```

How can you do this with jQuery?

Comment: So the values of the php variables are javascript arrays?

Comment: I've now put just the numbers in the example, but the php var. would have displayed a single numb. variable.

Comment: Why the weird indentation? And it's not at all clear what "this" is. What are you asking? And I think you're confusing the term "price" for "currency"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an array, I would use an object literal, as it allows you to map keys to values, rather than arbitrary array indexes.

```
var price = $.cookie('cur_price');
var map = {
    USD: 30,
    EUR: 24,
    GBP: 30
};

var active = map[price];

$('#price').html(active);
```

Furthermore, to consider the case where `cur_price` has not been set yet (first visit?) you might want to provide a default value:

```
var price = $.cookie('cur_price');
var map = {
    USD: 30,
    EUR: 24,
    GBP: 30
};

if (price == null) {
    price = 'GBP';
}

var active = map[price];

$('#price').html(active);
```

Furthermore, be warned that JavaScript is freely edited by the client; you should be validating all input on the server as well (especially when money is involved!).

Comment: The important thing is that you're using an object. That you initialised it with a literal is neither here nor there; making a point about it just helps propagate the myth that an "object literal" is some magical kind of actual container type.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal OTOH, since "everything in JavaScript is an object", the fact that he's using an object isn't significant in any way whatsoever.

Comment: @mblase75: OK, then an `Object` as opposed to an instance of any other object type. :)

Answer (score 3):

Create an associative-array-like object to store the prices:

```
var price = $.cookie('cur_price'); //this is USD, EUR or GBP
var prices = {
    'USD': 30,
    'EUR': 24,
    'GBP': 30
    };
$('#price').html(prices[price]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cookie = 'EUR';
var USD = 30; //to put this in a array
var EUR = 24; //seems the right way
var GBP = 30;
var active;

switch(cookie) {
    case 'EUR':
        active = EUR;
        break;
    case 'USD':
        active = USD;
        break;
    case 'GBP':
        active = GBP;
        break;
   default:
        active = -1; // maybe?
        break;
}
$('#price').html(active);
```